# Do you know any free newsgroup hosts?

Tags: newsgroups

I want to start a news group. I cannot use Yahoo Groups or Google Groups because they both are only open to people who have Yahoo ID or Google Account.

I want the group be open to anyone with any email service they may use.

Do you know any such service?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't mean a newsgroup, you mean a mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup some mailing list software like [GNU Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) (requires python and mailing server integration, so will probably work only on VDS) or use a free mailing list hosting like [FreeLists](http://www.freelists.org/) (uses Ecartis, another GNU software).